# How to get non-default interfaces in Delphi from a COM control?

Tags: delphi

I have imported a OCX control to Delphi, it shows the TLB and OCX classes. It works fine but I only can access to default interface.

How can I access to other interfaces?

Comment: Obviously you do not have the response. Delphi COM wrapper uses the default interface and I am asking how to use other interfaces. The question is clear, the COM object is irrelevant. In this case, it is a COM I created from .Net. Of course, before I ask here, I have been googling for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the `as` operator on a instance reference, e.g.:

```
(SomeOcxObject as IPersistStreamInit).InitNew;
```

or go the long way round and call `QueryInterface` yourself:

```
var
  x:IPersistStreamInit;
begin
  if SomeOcxObject.QueryInterface(IPersistStreamInit,x)<>S_OK then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  x.InitNew;
```

(I'm just using `IPersistStreamInit` here as an example, you didn't specify which interface you'd be using.)

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use the wrapped class but QueryInterface was a protected function. Now, I use the coClassCreator with QueryInterface as you suggested and it works like a charm.